# status bar turning to black for some reason

Tags: ios

For some reason, when I push to my next view, the status bar turns black.

What it should look like:

[image]

What it looks like:

[image]

This only for a specific set of view controllers. Here's my code:

```
//transitioning to uploadpicture, passing currentUser
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UploadPictureViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"uploadPictureVC"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Change UploadPictureViewController's View Background color To clear color

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your UploadPictureViewController implementation file.

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend edges 'under top bars'.